# Python: Add a delimiter to (int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, random_file))))

Tags: python, operating-system, delimiter

So I'm trying to print the number from a file name like `img_20.png`, which in this case would print `20`.

But when the file is a .mp4 file, Python reads `img_51.mp4` as `514` not `51`

Is there a way to add a delimiter `.` to this script so it would print `51` and not `514`?

#### Script

```
import os, sys, random

folder_path = "FOLDERPATH"

def upload_photo():
    list = os.listdir(folder_path)
    number_files = len(list)

    for i in range(number_files):
        e = 0
        try:
            random_file = random.choice(os.listdir(folder_path))
            print(random_file)
            print (int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, random_file))))
            break
        except:
            print("Hit except")

upload_photo()
```

#### Output

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_4.mp4
44
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_43.mp4
434
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_33.jpg
33
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_23.mp4
234
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_16.jpg
16
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_36.jpg
36
Matts-MacBook-Pro-5:Reddit matt$ python test.py
img_14.mp4
144
```

Comment: Try `print (int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, random_file.split('.')[0]))))`

Comment: @Mike67 thank you kind sir that works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

You can remove the file extension by using the `split` method.

Try this:

```
print (int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, random_file.split('.')[0]))))
```

This will also work if the file has no extension.